# Is there a way to search just a specific channel field without searching the title field?

Tags: search

Using ExpressionEngine 2's native search module, is there a way to search just a specific channel field  without searching the title field?  From what I can determine from the EE 2 docs, there are only 3 options with no way of keeping the title field from being searched.

[quoted from EE docs:](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/simple.html#search-in)

1. entries: The search will be conducted in the entry fields and **titles** of your channel. The associated comments will not be included.
2. everywhere: The search will be conducted in the **title**, entry fields, and in associated comments.
3. titles: The search will be conducted in the **title** of your entries. The channel entry fields and any associated comments will not be included.

My client wants a search to look only within a tag/s entered within a custom channel field, and exclude a keywords from the title tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are right, that isn't possible with a core EE install.  Low search and solspace's super search do that, but it also seems like this free add-on does it too in a very limited way: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/search-fields

Comment: Thanks for you response @UltraBob. **Question**: Using the add-on Search-Fields would I omit  `search:title="keyword"` to keep from searching title tags?

Comment: I'd say yes though, give it a try and see what happens ;)

Comment: What Natetronn said. As far as I could tell from the docs.  I've not used it.  Be aware, that is much less a replacement for the built in search module than are the two commercial add-ons I mentioned.

Comment: The docs say it's optional: https://github.com/croxton/Search_fields#searchfield--optional

Comment: yeah so just search:field1_you_want="keyword" search:field2_you_want="keyword" etc. As best I can tell.  Playing with it will give you a sense real fast if it does what you want.  Good to note this from the docs `This plugin can be memory intensive if you have lots of entries and search all channels.

It is NOT a replacement for the Search module, rather it is best used for custom filtering of entries in a single channel.`

Comment: Ok I am not seeing how the Add-on [Search Fields](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/search-fields) can be implemented with a EE search form. I can hard code a keyword for the channel field `search:custom_field="my_keyword" ` but how do I make this work from a search form? Would I replace my_keyword with `{search_results}`?

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that they can work in tandem.  I was suggesting that you MAY be able to use that add-on in lieu of EE search for a very limited set of functionality.  You might for example send you search through to the url and them fill keyword with a {segment_n} variable.  For a full featured search you'd want to probably go witha  more full featured addon.

Comment: I think I will give low Search a try

Comment: I hear great things ;)

Comment: Low Search Did the trick! Thanks for the suggestion.